# How to using AddMetrics in Asp.net Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I am use Asp.net core create a APM with AddMetrics; I follow these steps: https://www.app-metrics.io/web-monitoring/aspnet-core/reporting/

But it can never find the method `AddMetricsReportScheduler` in here:

```
services.AddMetricsReportScheduler();
```

I don't know `AddMetricsReportScheduler` in which namespace.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: https://github.com/AppMetrics/AppMetrics/issues/335#issuecomment-444963394

Comment: That‘s really helpful! Thank you very very much!